# USB connection to laptop motherboard

Tags: usb, connector, repair

I disassembled my HP DV7-3057NR (product #VU151UA#ABA) recently, in order to clean out the dust from the fan.

Anyway, I put it back together and now the 2 USB ports on the right hand side don't work any more. I took it apart again to investigate and found that the connection where the flat power cord running from the USB drive to the motherboard was loose. I eased the cable out and found that this piece where it connects to the motherboard is broken, so obviously no power is getting to the USB drive.

Does anybody know the specific name for this piece? And if it is replaceable without buying an entirely new motherboard?

[image: what is this piece called?]

[image: motherboard connection here]

Comment: While it would likely be repairable by an experienced surface mount tech either resoldering and perhaps gluing the existing broken connector, replacing it, or using an entirely new wiring scheme for the ports, I believe this laptop has 4 usb ports and your description only lists two as broken; a more pragmatic approach if you do not have substantial soldering experience might be to buy a hub and utilize only the ports on the other side.

Comment: thanks chris. i think you might be right. i only have 1 on the other side though (plus eSata).  and my usb speaker never played when connected to that side, so i was hoping it was fixable.

Comment: You can check in "Device manager" for that usb port, you may be missing a driver. Most versions of Windows will search for the correct driver for you.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to locate a connector like this, but you will need to put a lot of time into it. First determine if there is damage to the mother board. It is likely that some of the land patterns were damaged, looks like the connector was ripped from the board. If you find the MB is repairable, then it will be worth the search for a connector.

First look for any identifying logos or part numbers that may give a clue, then Google those numbers. If you get lucky, your done. Most times you won't find any number although. It is difficult to search the thousands of connector types from an electronics distributor web site, therefore I would visit several of the big competitors sites and request catalogs. You will receive 4" catalogs by snail mail shortly thereafter.

Once you have catalogs you will need to measure all aspects of the connector (I use a caliper for this) and thumb through many pages until you find a similar likeness. I would try places like: [Newark](http://www.newark.com/), [DigiKey](http://www.digikey.com/), and [Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/) are very popular here in the US. Your profile does not say where you are from, I'm assuming U.S.. If you do find one, then you have the task of soldering it to the MB. It is probably surface mounted, and that takes some skill. If you never have done it, I suggest you do a lot of practice first. Good luck!

Comment: i added a closeup of the connection point on the MB.  i can't tell if there is damage or not, but there probably is.

Comment: It appears to be a clean break. If you are not an experienced solderer, I suggest you pass it on to someone who is, or do a lot of practicing. This is not a beginner job. If done incorrectly the motherboard could be damaged beyond repair.